# bash - echo prints to the terminal

Tags: bash

I'm not that advanced at bash script so I suspect it may be something very simple. I made a script to run a URL with `curl` then parse the output using `grep` for some ids before appending it to a text file. By appending it to a text file, the ids are space delimited so I tried to replace the spaces with newlines like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

IDS=$(curl -v --silent "http://example.com" 2>&1 | grep -Eo 'data-user_id="[0-9]+"' | grep -Eo "[0-9]+")

echo ${IDS} >> "ids"
sed 's/ /\n/g' "ids"
```

But when I run this, I see the output of my file being written to the terminal, if I remove the last line (`sed`), the output disappears. Before I had used `tr` and the same thing happened. How do I stop this from happening?

Comment: @don_crissti Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Ok sorry I misunderstood there. I changed it to echo "$IDS" >> "ids" but it still happens.

Comment: I see the output of the file being printed to the terminal.

Comment: Yes, I see them appearing one per line. I didn't realise that was happening, even when I used `tr ' ' '\n' < "ids"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed` is printing the file with the substitution you told it to make.

I think a better idea might be the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

IDS=$(curl -v --silent "http://example.com" 2>&1 | grep -Eo 'data-user_id="[0-9]+"' | grep -Eo "[0-9]+")

echo "$IDS" | tr ' ' '\n' >> "ids"
```

This will echo `$IDS` and apply the space to new line translation before appending to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with perl

```
IDS=$(curl -sv http://example.com |& perl -lne 'print $1 if /data-user_id="(\d+)"/')
```